# mysql server detailed log

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I got those logs from syslog regarding mysql, however they are too brief in that they didn't tell me (or at least I think) what caused mysql to terminate with status 1. Can someone help me get more detailed logs?

Best,
Yuan

May 25 18:32:21 barnard kernel: [1587749.902491] type=1400 audit(1337985141.215:263):   apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=22272 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 25 18:32:21 barnard kernel: [1587750.181772] init: mysql main process (22276) terminated with status 1
May 25 18:32:21 barnard kernel: [1587750.181819] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
May 25 18:32:22 barnard kernel: [1587750.939171] init: mysql post-start process (22277) terminated with status 1
May 25 18:32:22 barnard kernel: [1587750.951160] type=1400 audit(1337985142.263:264): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=22310 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 25 18:32:22 barnard kernel: [1587751.226853] init: mysql main process (22314) terminated with status 1
May 25 18:32:22 barnard kernel: [1587751.226899] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
May 25 18:32:23 barnard kernel: [1587751.996106] init: mysql post-start process (22315) terminated with status 1
May 25 18:32:23 barnard kernel: [1587752.008270] type=1400 audit(1337985143.323:265): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=22348 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 25 18:32:23 barnard kernel: [1587752.246873] init: mysql main process (22352) terminated with status 1
May 25 18:32:23 barnard kernel: [1587752.246919] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped

Answer (score 0):

Same problems here. There are some bugs in the Ubuntu installation/upgrade/configuration settings for mysql 5.5 from 5.1. Others claim success with the steps below, but none worked for me. This first step will remove apparmor (a security service), so only do this temporarily during debugging:

```
sudo service apparmor teardown
```

Add the following line to your /etc/mysql/my.cnf under a [server] section:

```
character_set_server  = utf8
collation_server      = utf8_general_ci
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
```

But, like I said, this only worked for others, not me.

I'm running mysql off an SSD (`/` mounted on SSD) with `/var` and `/tmp` symlinked to a HD, do you have a similarly hybrid drive configuration? Maybe this is causing the "respawing too fast" part of our problem.